# Skrollr for Mobile

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, parallax, skrollr

I have been playing around with skrollr for awhile but I am getting stuck when trying to get it to consistently work well on mobile devices, I like how the demo works really well on mobile.

So, how is this implemented to get the desired result, if this is what I need at all? I also don't want to use the **skrollr-body** container as this causes other problems.

My test page is http://www.dalebailey.co.uk/idesignpixels/logo_test_2.html on mobiles this works but seems to screw up after orientation change or refresh.